# how to read template using swift mailer?

Tags: php, templates, swiftmailer

I have a `template file(html file)`. I have to include this template in my mail. How can i read template using `swift mailer`.

**I tried**

```
 $emailBody = readTemplateFile("http://www.something.in/guitar-mail.html");
    $emailBody_new = str_replace("#name#",$reg_fname,$emailBody);
    $emailBody_new  = str_replace("#email#",$url,$emailBody_new);
    $message->setBody($emailBody_new);
```

But in mail the `html` tags and `css` are displayed as plane text. How can i did this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally i got the solution..

replace the line

```
$message->setBody($emailBody_new);
```

with this

```
$message->setBody($emailBody_new, "text/html");
```

This worked..